# Is there a way to submit / view data into pro poker tools from a mobile device?

Tags: poker-tools, equity

Not sure if Pro Poker Tools is open source. IF not , is there anything similar  you could call from an android app that makes these calculations ? API that one could program a mobile app to call ?

Comment: Is there a standard for poker data?  If so please let me know where.

Comment: @Paparazzi I dont know of a standard .  I want to post and get data from the form at http://www.propokertools.com/simulations

Comment: I'm currently polishing up an iPhone App with this capability. Releasing at WSOP this summer.

Comment: @dustin Look forward to it . Let me know.  I would likely be able to help you make one on Android if they offered an API of some sort.

Comment: @Noodle email me at ddobrilo@gmail.com

Comment: @Dustin Emailed you moments ago